# How to calculate the cosine of two tensors in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

How can I apply Lambda function of Keras in Tensorflow? It is mentioned here -- https://keras.io/layers/core/

Comment: Straight from the docs you linked:  `Lambda(lambda x: cos(x))`

Comment: It's pretty clear in the documentation. Can you be a little more specific?

Comment: Do you mean cosine distance of tow tensor?